# Disk information Pane in Disk Utility is Black in LXDE

Tags: lxde, disk-utility

When I open Disk Utility, and click on one of the drives, the information (right)pane is black.  Any ideas?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: No theme, sorry, I forgot to mention that this happens under LXDE.

Comment: Could you provide more information , like you are using Lubuntu or have you installed LXDE-desktop Environment manually.

Comment: Installed LXDE-Desktop manually.

Comment: I experience this bug with the default theme in Blackbox as well. I'm very surprised to see such a severe bug in the default theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found out its a bug [See Here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-disk-utility/+bug/930719)

Even in the bug description it suggests a solution, changing the widget style to .... but that did not work for me.  What I have done is change the widget to Ambiance, and that fixed it, although it changed the look. Hopefully this bug will be fixed soon.